# convert char to double in matlab: str2double

Tags: matlab, char, double

```
X= 1:63;
n = 6;
% Y = int2bit(X,n)
y=dec2bin(X, n)
```

with this example I tried `str2double(y)` and got `NaN`

What is a problem?

Comment: This is explained pretty clearly in the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html

Answer (score 1):

`str2double` will only convert text that represents real or complex scalar values. Where `y` is a char array of binary values. It is basically interpreting `y` as one large integer. Hence, it will return NaN or Inf depending on the version of MATLAB you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use convertCharsToStrings and then use str2double

e.g

```
for i = 1:length(y)
  tempvar = convertCharsToStrings(y(i,:));
  x1(i) = str2double(tempvar);
end
```

OR if you just want to convert all string into double then use

arrayfun(@(x)str2double(convertCharsToStrings(x)),y,'Uniformoutput',false)